# How do I change the account confirmation URL generated by Devise in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

I am using the Devise gem in my project.

When a user signs up, Devise sends him a mail for account confirmation.
That mail contains an **account confirmation link**, and when the user clicks it, their account is activated and the user gets redirected to the [ root :to => 'home#welcome' ] page.

How do I change the URL of the above-mentioned **account confirmation link**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can re-define `new_user_confirmation_path` in `config/routes.rb` to accomplish this.